# How to add cropping preset in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

Would it be possible to add a preset to the cropping proportions list in Shotwell viewer?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. According to the developer: "Unfortunately, the crop presets are hard-coded. We could add more if they are commonly used sizes."

Comment: Could you possibly provide a source for the citation? I couldn't find it after searching around a bit.

Comment: I emailed the developer, and this is part of the response. So, no, no public source :)